# Usage of str.contains() applied to pandas data frame

Tags: python, string, pandas, jupyter

I am new to Python and Jupyter Notebook and I am currently following this tutorial: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tutorial/. So far I've imported the pandas library and a couple other things, and I've made a data frame 'df' which is just a CSV file of company profit and revenue data. I'm having trouble understanding the following line of the tutorial:

```
non_numberic_profits = df.profit.str.contains('[^0-9.-]')
```

I understand the point of what the tutorial is doing: identifying all the companies whose profit variable contains a string instead of a number. But I don't understand the point of [^0-9.-] and how the above function actually works.

My full code is below. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

df = pd.read_csv('fortune500.csv')
df.columns = ['year', 'rank', 'company', 'revenue', 'profit']
non_numberic_profits = df.profit.str.contains('[^0-9.-]')
df.loc[non_numberic_profits].head()
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_not_0-9.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `[^0-9.-]` is a so-called *regular expression*, which is a special text string for describing a search pattern. With regular expressions (or in short '*RegEx*') you can extract specific parts of a string. For example, you can extract `foo` from the string `123foo456`.

In RegEx, when using `[]` you define a range of characters that has to be matched. For example, `[bac]` matches `abc` in the string `abcdefg`. `[bac]` could also be rewritten as `[a-c]`.

Using `[^]` you can negate a character range. Thus, the RegEx `[^a-c]` applied to the above example would match `defg`.

Now here is a catch:
Since `^` and `-` have a special meaning when used in regular expressions, they have to be put in specific positions within `[]` in order to be matched literally. Specifically, if you want to match `-` literally and you want to exclude it from the character range, you have to put it **at the rightmost end** of `[]`, for example `[abc-]`.

**Putting it all together**
The RegEx `'[^0-9.-]'` means: 'Match all substrings that do **not** contain the digits 0 through 9, a dot (`.`) or a dash (`-`)'. You can see your regular expression applied to some example strings [here](https://regex101.com/r/MiII1E/2).

The pandas function `df.profit.str.contains('[^0-9.-]')` checks whether the strings in the `profit` column of your DataFrame match this RegEx and returns `True` if they do and `False` if they don't. The result is a pandas `Series` containing the resulting `True`/`False` values.

---

If you're ever stuck, the [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) are your friend.  Stack Overflow's [What Does this Regex Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) and [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/lRW6oG/1) are also good places to start.